# Search form - How to add text to user input

Tags: javascript, html

```
<form action='/search' method='get'>
  <input name='q' type='text'/><input type='submit' value='Go'/>
</form>
```

Basically, I want to add '&by-date=1' as suffix to every user input/search. For example, 'comics'

Result will be: http://www.example.com/search?q=comics&by-date=1

Is this possible to do without js? If not, what's the simplest way to achieve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a hidden field to your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="by-date" value="1" />
```

This will get appended to the GET request in the URL along with the other fields in your form. No JavaScript necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a hidden input field.

```
<input name='by-date' value='1' type='hidden'/>
```

Like this

```
<form action='/search' method='get'>
    <input name='by-date' value='1' type='hidden'/>
    <input name='q' type='text'/>
    <input type='submit' value='Go'/>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping. I think adding the hidden input field first looks neater.

Comment: wtf? I answered first, both answers are the same, and order of the attributes makes absolutely no difference. I don't get your reasoning.

Answer (score 0):

In the form action attribute you could try

```
action="/search?by-date=1"
```

it might work, I haven't tested it.

If not you could put a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="by-date" value="1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Then again you can put the by-date part first in the query:

`<form action='/search?by-date=1&' method='get'><input name='q' type='text'/><input type='submit' value='Go'/></form>`